# How to get an array's reference, make it scalar to use as an array key and make it back to a reference in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I need to take the reference to an array and somehow make it scalar so it can be the key of another array.
That *hash* should be reversible, this is, turn it again into a reference to manipulate the original array.
Is this possible?

Example:

```
<?php
$a = [1,2,3];
$b = hash_reference( $a );
$c = [$b => 'hi']; // this is legal because $b is a scalar
$d = unhash_reference( $b );
// here $d is a reference to $a just like if: $d = &$a
```

Comment: serialize/unserialize? json_encode/json_decode?

Comment: I don't think you can play that way with references in PHP, since they are not like C pointers. What about some workaround?

Comment: @uby yeah, that's what I'm looking for, can you think of a workaround for this?

Comment: @MarkBaker those functions will serialize the value, not the reference of the array. Besides, one of the array elements is a lambda function and it can't be serialized.

Comment: @Petruza, look at Jack Skinner answer, it seems like a nice solution. Just remember to use references (he forgot to)

Comment: http://php.net/SplObjectStorage ...!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in theory but I'd question the reason you need to do so.

Simply put, a string is a scalar type you can use as an array key - could you just json_encode($a) and use it as an array key?  It's terrible usage of json but functional within the example problem you've stated.

You're arguably best wrapping this requirement in some form of class.  In doing so you could match up some form of [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) with the array in question.

I scaffolded this crude example so that at least you're not using variable variables or other global scope.

```
class LookupTable {
    protected $data = [];
    public function store($x) { 
        $id = uniqid();
        $this->data[$id] = $x;
        return $id;
    }
    public function retrieve($id) {
        return $this->data[$id];
    }
}

$t = new LookupTable();
$a = [1,2,3];
$b = $t->store($a);
$c = [$b => 'hi'];
$d = $t->retrieve($b);
$r = &$a;

var_dump($a === $d); // is it the same object.
var_dump($a === $r); // its still the same object.
var_dump($c); // scalar array index! woohoo!
var_dump($d); // hey look, same object! :)
```

Comment: `$a` and `$d` are not the same object/array (if you edit any value in `$a`, `$d` is not modified). You should fix it using references in your `LookupTable` class.

Comment: It's free code, demonstrating a point of abstraction; nothing more nothing less :)  You're right of course - its a matter of usage & implementation.

Comment: `$a === $d` doesn't mean they are the same object, just 2 array with same values. I just thought you were missing the main point, here, ie: references, so I pointed it out, since this was what OP was asking. I think it's a really nice solution, I was just suggesting a small correction :)